# How to add images to svg to map each pie in the circle

Tags: reactjs, svg

How can I add an image to the path in my SVG and also rotate the text inside the path and make it closer to the edges of the path?

I am currently using the following code in my React application to create a roulette wheel with multiple sections. Each section is represented by a path that is filled with a specific color. I would like to add an image inside each path and also rotate the text inside the path and make it closer to the edges of the path.

```js
const RouletteWheel = () => {
  const items = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];
  const colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "brown", "purple"];

  const numItems = items.length;
  const angle = items.length === 1 ? 0 : 360 / numItems;

  return (
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" className="svg-wheel">
      {items.length > 1 ? (
        items.map((item, index) => {
          const x1 = 50 + 45 * Math.cos(angle * index * (Math.PI / 180));
          const y1 = 50 + 45 * Math.sin(angle * index * (Math.PI / 180));
          const x2 = 50 + 45 * Math.cos(angle * (index + 1) * (Math.PI / 180));
          const y2 = 50 + 45 * Math.sin(angle * (index + 1) * (Math.PI / 180));
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <defs>
                <path
                  id="text-path"
                  d={`M 50 50 L ${x1} ${y1} A 45 45 0 0 1 ${x2} ${y2} Z`}
                />
              </defs>
              <path
                key={`path-${index}`}
                id={`path-${index}`}
                d={`M 50 50 L ${x1} ${y1} A 45 45 0 0 1 ${x2} ${y2} Z`}
                fill={`${colors[index]}`}
              ></path>
              <text
                x={20}
                dy={25}
                fill="white"
                textAnchor="middle"
                fontSize={4}
                
              >
                <textPath transform={`rotate(100)`} xlinkHref={`#path-${index}`}>{item}</textPath>
              </text>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <circle key={"circle"} cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#pattern1)" />
      )}
    </svg>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  RouletteWheel(),
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following examples in plain SVG. In the first example I just implemented a solid color using the stroke of a circle (`#c1`).

In the second example I replaced the solid colors with images. Here the circle (`#c1`) acts as mask for the image. The tricky part is to place the image in the right angle together with the mask. In general all the rotations are calculated from a circle (360) split in 5 items. So 72 degrees each.

In both examples the text is placed along a circle (`#c2`) using a textpath element and the attribute startOffset. The dominant-baseline of the text is "hanging" -- so the text is place "under" the circle/arc. The placement of the text can be adjusted with the radius of circle (`#c2`).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c1" r="23" fill="none" stroke-width="46"
      stroke-dasharray="72 360" pathLength="360" />
    <circle id="c2" r="45" fill="none" pathLength="360" />
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(50 50)">
    <use href="#c1" stroke="blue" transform="rotate(0)" />
    <use href="#c1" stroke="red" transform="rotate(72)" />
    <use href="#c1" stroke="green" transform="rotate(144)" />
    <use href="#c1" stroke="yellow" transform="rotate(216)" />
    <use href="#c1" stroke="brown" transform="rotate(288)" />
    <text font-size="6" fill="white" text-anchor="middle"
      dominant-baseline="hanging">
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="36">item 1</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="108">item 2</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="180">item 3</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="252">item 4</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="324">item 5</textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1">
      <circle r="23" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="46"
        stroke-dasharray="72 360" pathLength="360" />
    </mask>
    <circle id="c2" r="45" fill="none" pathLength="360" />
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(50 50)">
    <g mask="url(#m1)">
      <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png" width="60"
        x="-30" y="-60" transform="rotate(126)" />
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#m1)" transform="rotate(72)">
      <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/300/080/fff.png" width="60"
        x="-30" y="-60" transform="rotate(126)" />
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#m1)" transform="rotate(144)">
      <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/300/800/fff.png" width="60"
        x="-30" y="-60" transform="rotate(126)" />
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#m1)" transform="rotate(216)">
      <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/300/f0f/fff.png" width="60"
        x="-30" y="-60" transform="rotate(126)" />
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#m1)" transform="rotate(288)">
      <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/300/022/fff.png" width="60"
        x="-30" y="-60" transform="rotate(126)" />
    </g>
    <text font-size="6" fill="white" text-anchor="middle"
      dominant-baseline="hanging">
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="36">item 1</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="108">item 2</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="180">item 3</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="252">item 4</textPath>
      <textPath href="#c2" startOffset="324">item 5</textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```